# why does make fail to recompile the binary on window 11 using msys2?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, mingw-w64, msys2

I am using msys2 bash shell to compile a C code with the help of `cmake` and `make`, in the build directory I run the command

`cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` followed by `make` resulting in the compiled binary

after running the `make` command one more time, I get the error message

```
app/src/CMakeFiles/app.dir/compiler_depend.make:4: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:112: app/src/CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

the c is a simple `hello, world` print statement
the structure of files is

```
.
├── app
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── src
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── main.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt

2 directories, 4 files
```

the `CMakeLists.txt` in the parent directory

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(app)
add_subdirectory(app)
```

the `CMakeLists.txt` in `app`

```
add_subdirectory(src)
```

the `CMakeLists.txt` in `src`

```
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    message ("Creating Debug build")
    add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -ggdb3)
endif ()

set(SOURCES  "main.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
```

I can recompile the binary only after running the command
`make rebuild_cache && make clean && make`

why do I get the above make error and is there a way to fix it?

the generated `Makefile` look like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/V2quRxCc)

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.26

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : %,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : SCCS/s.%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : s.%

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Command-line flag to silence nested $(MAKE).
$(VERBOSE)MAKESILENT = -s

#Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake.exe

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E rm -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /c/Users/malware/Desktop/first_app

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /c/Users/malware/Desktop/first_app/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
    /usr/bin/ccmake.exe -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake.exe --regenerate-during-build -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /c/Users/malware/Desktop/first_app/build/CMakeFiles /c/Users/malware/Desktop/first_app/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /c/Users/malware/Desktop/first_app/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean
.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named app

# Build rule for target.
app: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 app
.PHONY : app

# fast build rule for target.
app/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f app/src/CMakeFiles/app.dir/build.make app/src/CMakeFiles/app.dir/build
.PHONY : app/fast

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... app"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

Comment: Your `CMakeLists.txt` does not look bad at all.  It may be interesting to see the generated `Makefile` however I am not a Makefile expert.

Comment: It's not the makefile you care about.  The error message tells you the filename and line number where the error appears: `app/src/CMakeFiles/app.dir/compiler_depend.make:4`.  My suspicion is that you have added Windows-style paths as `#include` names in your `main.cpp`, containing drivespecs like `C:` etc.  That simply can't work.

Comment: Can you try with `cmake -GNinja` and `ninja` instead of `make`?